# display multiple geocharts in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I want to display 3 geocharts at the same time in one html page

(which query from multiple sheet -- one sheet for one chart).

as I 've read in the [document](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts)

I have one html file which contain 3 input sheet values

,input for region changes(radio button)

and 3 divs for chart (colormap/colormap2/colormap3)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>All Map</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="testscript.js">
 </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    
    <!--sheet id value
    
     //weee sheet !-->
 <input id="value1" value="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VouG7zZqHGB9CA6bxQx6CXX-TvOYkSqTmrN5DAj1Do/edit#gid=1175123524" type="hidden">
     <!--bat sheet!-->
        <input id="value2" value="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsugJPtz2EdHOLaiL0SvR9bh61H-vAgn9x1QBjIJ--c/edit?usp=sharing" type="hidden" >
        <!--pack sheet!-->
        <input id="value3" value="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zPP22gUPLDqTrvASIU3OXpmeHL_9IBS2O4z75g-1BHY/edit?usp=sharing" type="hidden" >
    
</head>
<body>
 
    
 <div>
  <input id="all" name="region" type="radio" value="all"><label for="all">All</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="africa" name="region" type="radio" value="002"><label for="africa">Africa</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="americas" name="region" type="radio" value="019"><label for="americas">Americas</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="europe" name="region" type="radio" value="150"><label for="europe">Europe</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input id="asia" name="region" type="radio" value="142"><label for="asia">Asia</label>
 </div>
 
        //DIV FOR CHARTS
        
  <div id='colormap'> </div>
        <div id='colormap2'> </div>
        <div id='colormap3'> </div>
       
</body>
</html>
```

In the script file, I have 1 for-loop function to get Sheet Value

,3 setonloadcallback

and 3 function of each map like this

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['geochart']});
 
 function checkinput() {
 var inputVal = document.getElementById();
 for (var i = 0; i < inputVal; i++){
      if (inputVal== "value1") {
          drawRegionsMap();
      }
    
      else if (inputVal == "value2")
    {
       drawRegionsMap2();
    }
    
      else
    {
     drawRegionsMap3();
     }
    
  }
 }
    
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap2);
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap3);
  
  function drawRegionsMap() { 
 
    var query = new google.visualization.Query((document.getElementById('value1').value));
    ......................
     }
     function drawRegionsMap2() { 
 
    var query = new google.visualization.Query((document.getElementById('value2').value));
    ..................................
     }
     
     function drawRegionsMap3() { 
 
    var query = new google.visualization.Query((document.getElementById('value3').value));
     
     
     ..............
```

**but the result display only one chart per one time on the page,everytime I refresh it will change to another chart which query from another sheet

but I want it to display 3 charts at the same time same page**

you can see the page here [click this link](http://sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/test1menu.html)

anyone can help please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I called a common function to show all charts.

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAll);

function drawAll(){
    drawRegionsMap();
    drawRegionsMap2();
    drawRegionsMap3();
}
```

Comment: tried that,nothing loaded-- are you loading different sheet for each chart? Do I have to change anything on function that get sheet value(url)? anyway,appreciate your help.

Comment: See the jsFiddle taken from google example and i edit the fiddle as i said in the answer. https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/5m8h1unn/

Comment: You can not read sheet value (saved in google drive) like this. `<input id="value2" value="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsugJPtz2EdHOLaiL0SvR9bh61H-vAgn9x1QBjIJ--c/edit?usp=sharing" type="hidden" >`. Additionally `var inputVal = document.getElementById();` this doesn't make sense. `for (var i = 0; i < inputVal; i++)` here `inputVal` is not a number as well.